# Unity3D controlling a ball

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In Unity3D, I'm working on simply controlling a ball. My goals are as follows:

- Allow the ball to rotate
- Move in the direction the ball is facing
- Ensure the ball is visually rotating as the ball is moving

What I am attempting to do is almost accomplished with this `character controller` script I wrote:

```
transform.Rotate (new Vector3(-Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal") * rotationSpeed, 0, 0));
Vector3 forward = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical") * transform.forward * moveSpeed;

controller.Move (forward);
controller.SimpleMove (Physics.gravity);
```

My problem with this script is that the ball does not visually "roll".

I attempted to solve this by using a `Rigidbody`:

```
float movementHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
float movementVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

Vector3 movementVector = new Vector3(movementHorizontal, 0.0f, movementVertical);
GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(movementVector * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
```

But in this case, you are unable to rotate anymore then 180 degrees using WAD like the first example. Although it does solve the visual problem.

How is it that I can allow my ball to rotate with the "A" and "D" keys, and then go in the direction the ball is facing with "W" while also visually rotating?

Comment: Try with ***transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * 2)***, I know I have an example somewhere....

Comment: My problem with when i rotate my ball like that, using the first script, when the ball rolls it will move vertically because the ball will be facing up due to the "transform,forward" call

Comment: Take a look here: https://github.com/heldersepu/hs-unity/tree/master/Labyrinth

Comment: I'm trying to use the code from the move3D method and can't seem to get much result other then the ball rocking back and forth

Comment: Take a look at my answer.. if that is not what you need, add a sample project to GitHub and we can figure out where is the issue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look a this example:
http://unity3d.azurewebsites.net/Labyrinth/

- move the ball with the arrow keys
- move the camera with the keypad *(#5 will chase)*
- zoom in/out with - + keys
- change perspective with V key

The code behind the movement is here:
https://github.com/heldersepu/hs-unity/blob/master/Labyrinth/Assets/Movement.cs

Comment: I appreciate all the help, but again my problem is the visual aspect. The script will only work if i freeze the rotation. I want my ball to rotate visually while it moves

Comment: @Ryan Can you add your project to GitHub?

Comment: @Ryan I just noticed your comment, I was working on another example: http://unity3d.azurewebsites.net/BallControl/

Comment: Can you link a github for that?

Comment: Everything is on the same repo: https://github.com/heldersepu/hs-unity/
 ...Just look for BallControl

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151171/discussion-between-heldersepu-and-ryan).